# Putting a raw piece of meat in pot on Erev Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, cooking-bishul

[Orach Chaim Siman 253 Seif 1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.253.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) talks about in which situation are you allowed to keep food on a fire on shabbos and in the middle of the seif it says,

> ואם נתן בה **חתיכה חיה** מותר כאלו היתה כולה חיה דע"י כך מסיח דעתו ממנה
>
> If a **raw piece (of meat)** is put into the pot, it is permitted just as if it would consist entirely of raw (meat) since now he will not pay attention to the entire pot.

My question is with regard to adding a raw piece of meat to a fully cooked pot of food on erev shabbos. How big does this piece of meat have to be? A small cube that's a square inch good enough? Or it has to be a big piece... and if so how big? Please provide sources.

Comment: Based on the reason it would have to be a big enough piece that you wouldn't eat the rest of the dish while that piece is raw and big enough that it won't cook so quickly that someone might think to raise the fire to have it be done sooner. Is there another option? Or are you just looking for some way to further quantify that?